# Evaluation of $L^p$ function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Functions in $L^p$ are only defined $µ$-almost everywhere, so for a given evaluation point $x$, $F(x)$, $f\in L^p$ can be changed to any value, so in general it would not be well-definied to just write $y=f(x)$.
(Every representant $f$ of the equivalence class $F$ can be evaluated, okay. But this doesn't help.)

What is needed to have a well-defined evaluation mapping $(F,x) \mapsto F(x)$ , and **how is this problem solved canonically**? 
It would be enough for example that F is piecewise continuous, then I could define the evualation at every continuous part. But isn't much less (for example piecewise one-sided continuity?) enough?

And if you take for example Sobolev spaces, and consider the weak derivative of $F:x \mapsto |x|$. Does it follow from the definition of weak derivative in Sobolev spaces that we choose the continuous representant of $F'$ in $L^p$, and define the evaluation of the weak derivative only on the continuous part? How is this problem handled?

Answer (score 2):

Canonical choices for values of measurable functions ... see the [theory called "lifting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_theory)
For example:
*Topics in the Theory of Lifting*
(Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 2. Folge, 1969)
Alexandra Ionescu Tulcea, C. Ionescu Tulcea

Comment: But... there's no lifting on $L^p$ for $1 \leq p \lt \infty$ (and I wouldn't count a lifting as a *canonical* choice).

Comment: So, in the important cases for $L^p$, $p<\infty$ there is no good way to do so?

Comment: In $L^p$ there is certainly a linear lifting, but it is just that there is none that preserves products (as we require in $L^\infty$).